# Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match range

Tags: html, google-apps-script, sidebar

I'm receiving this script error when I try to submit a change from an HTML side bar to a sheet in a different workbook.

"Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 5 but the range has 1."

Here is the code I am using to search an ID of an active row within a specific column of a different workbook. The last line of code that is commented out updates the entire row in the other workbook. The line above is my attempt to update only column 5 when the row is located. Can someone help me fix it please?

GS:

```js
function setSelectedRow(row) {
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  let sheet = cell.getSheet();
  var active_range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  var id = sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 1).getValue();
  Logger.log(id)
  var sh2 =SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mtmEMTtdEWk-MqC-5cXIGTefibUirpSjtaFQwAPAO5Q').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const searchCol = 1;
  const range = sh2.getRange(2, searchCol,sh2.getLastRow());
  const data = range.getValues();
  const result = data.finder(id);
  Logger.log(result)
  sh2.getRange(result+2,5).setValues([row]);
  //sh2.getRange(result+2,1,1,sh2.getLastColumn()).setValues([row]);


}

Array.prototype.finder = function(val){
  if(val == "") return false;
  for(let i=0;i<this.length;i++){
    if(this[i].toString().indexOf(val) > -1) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

HTML:

```html
  <script>
  function mainContainerMouseEnter() {
    try {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
        function (row) {
          row = JSON.parse(row);
          document.getElementById("currentRange").value = row.range;
          document.getElementById("column1").value = row.row[0];
          document.getElementById("column2").value = row.row[1];
          document.getElementById("column3").value = row.row[2];
          document.getElementById("column4").value = row.row[3];
          document.getElementById("column5").value = row.row[4];
        }
      ).withFailureHandler(
        function (err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      ).getSelectedRow();
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert("Error in mainContainerMouseEnter: "+err);
    }
  }
  
  function submitOnClick() {
    try {
      row = [];
      row[0] = document.getElementById("column1").value;
      row[1] = document.getElementById("column2").value;
      row[2] = document.getElementById("column3").value;
      row[3] = document.getElementById("column4").value;
      row[4] = document.getElementById("column5").value;
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(
        function (err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      ).setSelectedRow(row);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert("Error in submitOnClick: "+err);
    }
  }

  (function () {
    document.getElementById("mainContainer").addEventListener("mouseenter",mainContainerMouseEnter);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: How is finder different from indexOf()?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
sh2.getRange(result + 2, 5).setValues([row]);
```

to this line:

```
sh2.getRange(result + 2, 5,[row].length,row.length).setValues([row]);
```

I think you also might want this:

```
const data = range.getValues();
```

to be this:

```
const data = range.getValues().flat();
```

Comment: Thanks. That sends the 5 columns into the right row but starting from column 5 of the sheet. Can I get the row[4] value from html into column 5?